# Does Rails 4.1 still have the asset_path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, select2-rails

In the [upgrade guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) it states

> Rails 4.0 removed the ActionController::Base.asset_path option. Use the assets pipeline feature.

I am currently in the process of upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1. In my app I use the select2-rails gem and in my js I add an image for the select menu options:

```
//mycode.js.erb
function format(image) {
    var image_path = "<%= asset_path('" + image.id.toLowerCase() +"') %>"
    return "<img class='flag' src='" + image_path + "' />";
}
```

The above worked in my Rails 3.2 app but I seemed to have broken it with my upgrade to 4.1 and now receive the following error:

`Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file '" + image.id.toLowerCase() +"'`

Is the asset_path helper still available in Rails 4.1? If yes, any ideas on where I may have gone wrong?

**Update**

The code above is in my .js.erb file which allows me to have Ruby code within my js file. This currently works well in my Rails 3.2 project. I am doing this as select2 allows us to format the display of our select menu items as per the below example:

```
//sample.js
function format(state) {
  if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
  return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() +   ".png'/>" + state.text;
}
```

My understanding was that it is correct usage to use the asset pipeline paths rather than manually adding something like 'assets/images/icons/small'

Comment: how are you combining JS and CSS like that... better yet, why... Please learn the difference between client-side and server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the question to highlight why I have used a .js.erb file.